# Extract number from text in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash, kibana, analyzer

I'm using logstash to ship logs to ElasticSearch 5.1 instance and using Kibana 5.1 to show all the results.

How can I extract only the numbers from a known pattern string of the log, and then summarize all the numbers per minute?

For example, my log lines contain this text:

"Processing 53 records"

"Processing 45 records"

"Processing 97 records"

I want to create a field called **processed_records**, which get values 53, 45, 97 respectively, then I want to create another field called **processed_records_sum**, which contains the summary of **processed_records** per minute.

I'm new to ELK, So I don't know If I need to make a change in the logstash conf file and/or Kibana

Comment: You have to write a grok filter to catch number of records from the logs. Have you written any?

Comment: I didn't know about the grok filter. Will check it out soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the number of records, the log file will need to be matched against a Grok parser, for example:

```
%{WORD} %{NUMBER:processed_records} %{WORD}
```

As your log file is probably more complicated than this, there are online tools to help:

- To get a list of Grok patterns see
  https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns
- To construct new Grok statements see
  http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/constructionstep
- To test a Grok statement http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result or
  https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Once your log file has been parsed, the record count will be stored in the **processed_records** field in Elasticsearch.

Summing (**processed_records_sum**) the data will need to be done at query time - you cannot calculate the sum when inserting the log records into Elasticsearch.

When summing at query time, either use the Kibana UI or if writing Elasticsearch DSL then use aggregation.

Comment: Thank's, It was much helpful!

Answer (score 0):

While not performant, if you *must* avoid reindexing, you could use scripted fields in kibana.

Introduction here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields

- enable painless regex support by putting the following in your elasticsearch.yaml:

  > script.painless.regex.enabled: true
- restart elasticsearch
- create a new scripted field in Kibana through Management -> Index Patterns -> Scripted Fields
- select painless as the language and number as the type
- create the actual script, for example:

```
def logMsg = params['_source']['log_message'];
if(logMsg == null) {
 return -10000;
}
def m = /.*Processing ([0-9]+) records.*$/.matcher(params['_source']['log_message']);
if ( m.matches() ) {
   return Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))
} else {
   return -10000
}
```

- you must reload the website completely for the new fields to be executed, simply re-doing a search on an open discover site will not pick up the new fields. (This almost made me quit trying to get this working -.-)
- use the script in discover or visualizations

While I do understand, that it is not performant to script fields for millions of log entries, my usecase is a very specific log entry, that is logged 10 times a day in total and I only use the resulting fields to create a visualization or in analysis where I reduce the candidates through regular queries in advance.

Would be interesing if it is possible to have those fields only be calculated in situations where you need them (or they make sense & are computable to begin with; i.e. to make the "return -1000" unnecessary). Currently they will be applied and show up for every log entry.
You can generate scripted fields inside of queries like this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html but that seems a bit too much of burried under the hood, to maintain easily :/

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a dissect plugin to achieve the same;

```
dissect { mapping => { "message" => "%{processing} %{processed_records} %{records}" }
```

and then you have the summary configured in Kibana accordingly!